# feathers js - Login through new strategy throw Forbidden error

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I've created new strategy `admin` and trying to login by `POST /authentication` with below body:

```
{
    "strategy": "admin",
    "username": "CCCC",
    "password": "myPassword"
}
```

error:

```
{
    "name": "Forbidden",
    "message": "You have no permission to find admin",
    "code": 403,
    "className": "forbidden",
    "errors": {}
}
```

services/admin/admin.hooks.js

```
const { disallow, keep, required, iff, sequelizeConvert } = require('feathers-hooks-common');
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;
const checkPermissions = require('feathers-permissions');
const errors = require('@feathersjs/errors');

const {
  hashPassword, protect
} = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
      checkPermissions({
        roles: ['superadmin', 'admin'],   // I am using account with role "member"
        error: false,
      }),
    ],
    find: [
      iff(context => !context.params.permitted,
        context => {
          throw new errors.Forbidden('You have no permission to find admin');
        }
      ),],
  },

};
```

default.json

```
{
  ....
  "authentication": {
    "entity": "user",
    "service": "users",
    "adminService": "admin",
    "secret": "XXXXXX=",
    "authStrategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local",
      "admin",
    ],
    "jwtOptions": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
    "admin": {
      "service": "admin",
      "usernameField": "username",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
  },


}
```

authentication.js

```
const { AuthenticationService, AuthenticationBaseStrategy, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { OAuthStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');
const { expressOauth } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');
const { discard, iff, isProvider, lowerCase, keep } = require('feathers-hooks-common')

const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const { omit } = require('lodash');

class SessionAuthService extends AuthenticationService {

  constructor(app, configKey) {
    super(app, configKey);

    app.on('logout', async (authResult, params, context) => {
      await app.service(this.configuration.service).patch(authResult.user.id, { session: null }).catch(e => null);
      await app.service(this.configuration.adminService).patch(authResult.user.id, { session: null }).catch(e => null);
    });
  }

  async getPayload(authResult, params) {
    const service = authResult.authentication.strategy == 'admin' ? this.configuration.adminService : this.configuration.service;
    const payload = await super.getPayload(authResult, params);
    const user = await this.app.service(service).patch(authResult.user.id, { session: uuidv4() });
    return {
      ...payload,
      ses: user.session,
    };
  }

  async verifyAccessToken(accessToken, options, secret) {
    const verifyResult = await super.verifyAccessToken(accessToken, options, secret);
    const user = await this.app.service(this.configuration.service).get(verifyResult.sub).catch(e => null);
    const admin = await this.app.service(this.configuration.adminService).get(verifyResult.sub).catch(e => null);
    if (user || admin) {
      const { session } = user || admin;
      if (verifyResult.ses != session) {
        throw new errors.NotAuthenticated('token revoked');
      }
    }
    return verifyResult;
  }

}

class JWTWithAdminStrategy extends JWTStrategy {
  async getEntity(id, params) {
    const { entity } = this.configuration;
    const entityService = this.entityService;

    if (entityService === null) {
      throw new NotAuthenticated(`Could not find entity service`);
    }

    const user = await entityService.get(id, omit(params, 'provider')).catch(e => null);
    const admin = await this.app.service(this.authentication.configuration.adminService).get(id, omit(params, 'provider')).catch(e => null);
    if (admin && !admin.enabled) {
      throw new errors.NotAuthenticated('disabled');
    };

    const result = user || admin;
    const service = user ? entityService : this.app.service(this.authentication.configuration.adminService);

    if (!params.provider) {
      return result;
    }

    return service.get(id, { ...params, [entity]: result });
  }

}

class AdminStrategy extends LocalStrategy {
  get configuration () {
    const authConfig = this.authentication.configuration;
    const config = super.configuration || {};

    return {
      hashSize: 10,
      service: config.service,
      entity: authConfig.entity,
      entityId: authConfig.entityId,
      errorMessage: 'Invalid login',
      entityPasswordField: config.passwordField,
      entityUsernameField: config.usernameField,
      ...config
    };
  }
  async getEntity(result, params) {
    const entityInfo = await super.getEntity(result, params);
    if (!entityInfo.enabled) {
      throw new errors.NotAuthenticated('disabled');
    }
    return entityInfo;
  }
}

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new SessionAuthService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTWithAdminStrategy());
  authentication.register('admin', new AdminStrategy());
 
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());

};
```